# Magento 2: System upgrade fails Readiness Check (always_populate_raw_post_data = 0)

Tags: magento2, upgrade, cron

I am trying to upgrade Magento 2.07 to 2.1. I pass all the checks apart from the one below:

> Your PHP Version is 5.6.22, but always_populate_raw_post_data = 0. $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated from PHP 5.6 onwards and will be removed in PHP 7.0. This will stop the installer from running. Please open your php.ini file and set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1. If you need more help please call your hosting provider.

I had this problem on setup and got around it by editing my .user.ini by adding

> always_populate_raw_post_data = -1

But this seems to be ignored by the upgrade utility. Any ideas? I am thinking it might be because my cron jobs are loading the server php.ini and not my .user.ini?

Comment: what does phpinfo() say? I have the same problem and if i check phpinfo() I see always_populate_raw_post_data -1 for both Local Value and Master Value.. but i still get the same error you get

Comment: Hi @mrzhero my phpinfo() says -1 for the local value. Which works perfect for the initial Magento 2 install. But the upgrade system seems to ignore this, possible bug I think. Since my store isn't very big I've just set up a fresh install of 2.1 and going to import everything in rather than keep pulling my hair out trying to get it to update.

Comment: You can try adding this to Magento's `.htaccess`: `php_value always_populate_raw_post_data = -1`. Issues like yours happen because there are typically at minimum two sets of PHP configurations: one for the PHP CLI and one for the web server. In addition, if you have multiple PHP versions installed, it gets more complicated.

Comment: @Steve Johnson I tried, still no luck. I made a test file that prints the output of `$iniSetting = intVal(ini_get('always_populate_raw_post_data'));`: the result is `-1`. When I run the Readiness Check however, it says `always_populate_raw_post_data = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem on my server.

Check `phpinfo()` on your browser.

Check `php -i | grep php.ini` via SSH.

Compare the value of `Loaded Configuration File`: on my server, they were 2 different files. My host provider said they could change only the file I saw in phpinfo() and not the other one. Since Magento checks the value by running cron, it gets the configuration that I can't change.

So the only way for me was to bypass the checker.

I edited `{magento_root}/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/PhpReadinessCheck.php`:

```
private function checkPopulateRawPostSetting(){
    // HHVM and PHP 7does not support 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to be set to -1
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.0.0-beta') >= 0 || defined('HHVM_VERSION')) {
        return [];
}

return []; // <- THIS IS THE LINE I ADDED

[...]
```

After the cron jobs get executed, if you check `{magento_root}/var/.setup_cronjob_status`, you should see:

```
"php_settings_verified": {
        "responseType": "success",
        "data": []
    }
```

Run again the Readiness Check: the PHP Settings Check gets a green light.

Dirty workaround, but I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: Dirty workaround, yes.  Since you're running Mage 2, why not use PHP 7.0 instead?  They can run side-by-side like PHP 4 and 5 did for years on hosts.